# How efficient is efficient when it comes to Polynomial Time Algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I hope this is the right place for this question.

Polynomial time algorithms! How do polynomial time algorithms (PTAs) actually relate to the processing power, memory size (RAM) and storage of computers?

We consider PTAs to be efficient. We know that even for a PTA, the time complexity increases with the input size `n`. Take for example, there already exists a PTA that determines if a number is prime. But what happens if I want to check a number this big https://justpaste.it/3fnj2? Is the PTA for prime check still considered efficient? Is there a computer that can compute if such a big number like that is prime?

Whether yes or no (maybe no, idk), how does the concept of polynomial time algorithms actually apply in the real world? Is their some computing bound or something for so-called polynomial time algorithms?

I've tried Google searches on this but all I find are mathematical Big O related explanations. I don't find articles that actual relate the concept of PTAs to computing power. I would appreciate some explanation or links to some resources.

Comment: I mean, practically speaking, any algorithm that runs in O(n^2) or longer is generally considered too inefficient to be useful in practice. O(n) or O(n log n) is about the worst scaling that is tolerable in the **average case**. Note, there are plenty of algorithms that are practical, have a terrible worst-case runtime, but their average runtime is acceptable on a suitable set of data. For example, quick-sort, certain max-flow algorithms, and the simplex algorithm. The last example I gave, the simplex algorithm, actually scales exponentially in the worst case.

Comment: I like the first part of your answer. So why then are polynomial time algorithms (even of O^4) considered efficient. Does the point of calling them efficient only serve when relating them to other (not efficient algorithms) e.g. of 2^n.

Comment: Like price, efficiency is a relative term. Is $10,000 expensive? For a car, no. For a phone, yes. Is O(n log n) efficient? For binary search, no. For sorting, yes.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speedup speedup is a measure that relates computing power to the algorithm.

Comment: It is *not true at all* that "we consider PTAs to be efficient".  What *is* generally true is that we consider problems that have no polynomial-time solutions to be hard.

Comment: There is a precise answer to your question.  But it requires understanding the big-O explanations that you've discounted. Like it or not, math IS the language for discussing what algorithms can do.

Comment: @btilly I guess I either accept the math or forget about it. Nice angle :)

Comment: @RaymondChen,,, that makes sense... Thanks. So it comes done to relation after all as pointed by Idog (comment above yours). Saying a PTA is efficient (though it may actually not be efficient in terms of computing power) compared to some other algorithm provides a way to simply guage things and give us a sense of what is maybe possible, and what is completely not possible (hard). Am I making sense?

Comment: You are taking the precise technical term "efficient" and applying natural-language semantics to it. In the realm of algorithmic analysis, "efficient" is defined to mean "polynomial". That doesn't mean that it really *is* efficient. Just that we're calling it "efficient' because we have to give it a name. "[Do theorists actually consider an O(n¹⁰⁰)-time algorithm fast in practice? No.](https://medium.com/probably-approximately-correct/polynomial-time-and-efficient-algorithms-16481666827b)" A 90-degree angle is called a "right" angle, but that doesn't mean that the others are "wrong".

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to explain.

1. Regarding Polynomial Time as efficient is just an arbitrary agreement. The mathematicians have defined a set Efficient_Algorithms = {P algorithm, where P Polynomial}. That is only a mathematical definition. Mathematicians don't see your actual hardware and they don't care for it. They work with abstract concepts. Yes, scientists consider O(n^100) as efficient.
   But you cannot compare one to one statements from theoretical computer science with computer programs running on hardware. Scientists work with formulas and theorems while computer programs are executed on electric circuits.
2. The Big-Oh notation does not help you for comparing implementations of an algorithms. The Big-Oh notation compares algorithms but not the implementations of them. This can be illustrated as follows. Consider you have a prime checking algorithm with a high polynomial complexity. You implement it and you see it does not perform well for practical use cases. So you use a profiler. It tells you where the bottle neck is. You find out that 98% of the computations time are matrix multiplications. So you develop a processor that does exactly such calculations extremely fast. Or you buy the most modern graphics card for this purpose. Or you wait 150 years for a new hardware generation. Or you achieve to make most of these multiplications parallel. Imagine you achieved somehow to reduce the time for matrix multiplications by 95%. With this wonderful hardware you run your algorithm. And suddenly it performs well. So your algorithm is actually efficient. It was only your hardware that was not powerful enough. This is not an thought experiment. Such dramatic improvements of computation power are reality quite often.
3. The very most of algorithms that have a polynomial complexity have such because the problems they are solving are actually of polynomial complexity. Consider for example the matrix multiplication. If you do it on paper it is O(n^3). It is the nature of this problem that it has a polynomial complexity. In practice and daily life (I think) most problems for which you have a polynomial algorithm are actually polynomial problems. If you have a polynomial problem, then a polynomial algorithm is efficient.
4. Why do we talk about polynomial algorithms and why do we consider them as efficient? As already said, this is quite arbitrary. But as a motivation the following words may be helpful. When talking about "polynomial algorithms", we can say there are two types of them.

- The algorithms that have a complexity that is even lower than polynomial (e.t. linear or logarithmic). I think we can agree to say these are efficient.
- The algorithms that are actually polynomial and not lower than polynomial. As illustrated above, in practice these algorithms are oftentimes polynomial because they solve problems that are actually of polynomial nature and therefore require polynomial complexity. If you see it this way, then of course we can say, these algorithms are efficient.

5. In practice if you have a linear problem you will normally recognise it as a linear problem. Normally you would not apply an algorithm that has a worse complexity to a linear problem. This is just practical experience. If you for example search an element in a list you would not expect more comparisons than the number of elements in the list. If in such cases you apply an algorithm that has a complexity O(n^2), then of course this polynomial algorithm is not efficient. But as said, such mistakes are oftentimes so obvious, that they don't happen.
6. So that is my final answer to your question: In practice software developers have a good feeling for linear complexity. Good developers also have a feeling of logarithmic complexity in real life. In consequence that means, you don't have to worry about complexity theory too much. If you have polynomial algorithm, then you normally have a quite good feeling to tell if the problem itself is actually linear or not. If this is not the case, then your algorithm is efficient. If you have an exponential algorithm, it may not be obvious what is going on. But in practice you see the computation time, do some experiments or get complains from users. Exponential complexity is normally not deniable.